# Tools for creating gene coexpression networks

Tags: python, gene-expression

What are some good tools (in Python if possible) for creating gene co-expression networks from RNA seq data?

Answer (score 1):

After looking around, it seems like the [Camoco library](https://camoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is suitable.

Comment: It would be nice to hear from the R crowd

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the size of your data. If you have enough RAM available, then you may directly compute a correlation-based distance matrix using the *cor()* function (with method="spearman" or method="pearson"). But you may also give a try to Mutual Information distance using the **Parmigene** (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parmigene/index.html) R package or partial correlations with the **Corpcor** (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpcor/index.html) R package.
If you have a large expression matrix, remember to use the excellent **data.table** package and its *fread()* function.